# Hide Header part in few pages in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am new in angular2. I have a url users/1/posts. I want to hide header in posts index page. I have fetched ids from url like this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((val: Event) => {
  if (val instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
    this.userId= val.state.root.firstChild.params['user_id'] || 0;
  }
});
```

This is the header component that I am using in the application and want to hide this in posts index page.

```
<div class= "row"  [hidden]="isHidden()">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-header " style="box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);">
    abc
  </nav>
</div>
```

and this method I wrote in .ts file:

```
isHidden() {
  let list = ['/users/userId/posts'],
  route = this.location.path();
  return (list.indexOf(route) > -1);
};
```

but its not working and if I am using this then header part of users index page is getting hiden:

```
 isHidden() {
  let list = ['/users'],
  route = this.location.path();
  return (list.indexOf(route) > -1);
};
```

So, could anyone please help me in hiding header in posts index page?

Comment: Be more clear please.. what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to hide header part in this url users/:user_id/posts means in posts index page.

Comment: You want do hide one of the request headers? Or wnat to hide part of the url? Or something else?

Comment: I want to hide request headers.

Comment: So please add your request code.. Which header do you want to remove?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: @ltiel please check the code.